# mysql help: Joining Two Tables With a Where Clause and Displaying Rows From the Other

Tags: mysql, inner-join, outer-join

Write SELECT statement to list products with vendor data for products purchased after 2010-1-15.

I have tried multiple different commands with the best results being from:

```
 select * from product where p_indate > '2010-1-15';
```

Lists information from the product table instead of vendor
and

```
 select p_indate from product right join vendor on p_indate > '2010-1-15';
```

Just lists the p_indate with 11 duplicate values for each date that meets the conditions

I have tried searching for awhile now and nothing seems to fit exactly my question, thanks for the help!

Here are the tables: 
Vendor:

```
v_code(primary)|v_name|v_contact|v_areacode|v_phone|v_state|v_order
```

product

```
p_code(primary)|p_descript|p_indate(foreign)|p_qoh|p_min|p_price|p_discount|v_code(foreign)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify p.* and v.* in the select to get all the product and vendor data

```
SELECT p.*, v.*
FROM product p
JOIN vendor v ON p.v_code = v.v_code 
WHERE p.p_indate > '2010-01-15' ;
```

You can also pick and choose your fields to return by prefixing them with p.field name or v.field_name

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! ultimately in ended up using 
`SELECT p.p_indate,
 v.*

FROM product p

JOIN vendor v ON 
p.v_code = v.v_code 

WHERE 
p.p_indate > '2010-01-15' ;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `on` clause to pick out the columns that the tables have in common:

```
select  p_indate.*, vendor.*
from product 
right join vendor on p_indate.v_code=vendor.v_code 
where p_indate > '2010-1-15';
```

Comment: This worked to get a column that shows all the p_indates they have in common that are > 2010-1-15, but it displays no further information, is there a way I can get this column with the corresponding information from the vendor table?

Comment: `SELECT p_indate.*, vendor.* 
FROM product 
RIGHT JOIN vendor ON p_indate.v_code=vendor.v_code 
WHERE p_indate > '2010-1-15';`  will return every column from both tables.  This is not efficient.  Best to specify only those columns you are actually using.  Don't forget to `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS.